# Writing to Excel Sheet using Pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to update values in an excel sheet using Pandas but the changes overwrites the whole file instead of just a value in in a sheet.

```
          sheet_1 = pd.read_excel(r"Documents\TestPage.xlsx", 0)
          sheet_1.loc[0, 'Test1'] = 10
          sheet_1.to_excel("Documents\TestPage.xlsx", sheet_name= 'sheet_1')
```

My code intends to change only Test1 value but instead it overwrites the entire new file losing other pages. 
I noticed that others facing similar issues but I could figure out looking at the answer.

Appreciate your help and guidance.

Cheer

Comment: It seems like there is no way to only access one sheet, modify it and then save it without overwriting the others. The easiest way seems to be @Eli Mitz suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the pandas [ExcelWriter class](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) to do what you want.

The specific example from the link above is:

```
with ExcelWriter('path_to_file.xlsx') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2')
```